# Sort Eloquent models on relationship (one>many)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I've got a model called "Lesson" which has a `->hasMany()` relationship which represent the dates for this lesson.

To retrieve every lesson with a date within a certain time-span I use a `whereHas`:

```
$list = Lesson::whereHas('dates', function ($query)  use ($start, $end) {
   $query->where('date','>=', $start->format('Y-m-d'))
         ->where('date','<=', $end->format('Y-m-d'));
})->get()
```

This works as expected, but I now want to sort the `$list` by the 'smallest' date associated with the lesson.

Preferably I wish to use the Eloquent models, as there are some needed methods in the model. But if it's not possible, than a 'plain' sql statement could also be used.

Comment: What do you mean by `smallest` date?

Comment: smallest = oldest date

Comment: So, why don't you orderBy date in desc order?

Comment: Because there can be more then one dates attached to the lesson, so mysql doesn't know which date to use to order by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the available methods of [Laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#available-methods).This code should do it.

```
$sortedLessons = $lessons->sortBy(function ($lesson) {
    $dates = $lesson->dates;
    $minDate = $dates->sortBy('date');
    return $minDate;
});
```

I assumed that you have a field date in your date model.

Comment: Never knew the `sortBy()` method accepted a function.

Comment: yes it does accept callbacks, and not only sortBy() also other collection methods like filter() and each() accept callbacks as well